# Windows Store App - How to goback from binding command

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, commandbinding

I'm a little bit confusing about binding commands and frame navigation in Windows Store Apps. I started a project using Grid App (XAML) template from Windows Store and added an appbar as follow:

```
<AppBar IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource SaveAppBarButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Item.UpdateItem}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</AppBar>
```

Then I created a property in my class and a method like:

```
public ICommand UpdateItem 
{
    get { return new UpdateItemCommand(this); }
}

void Save()
{
    SampleDataSource.UpdateGroup(this);

    SampleDataSource.SaveFileAsync();
}
```

So far everything is fine, the group was updated and file saved too. Here is my implementation for UpdateItemCommand class:

```
class UpdateItemCommand : ICommand
{
    public UpdateItemCommand(SampleDataItem viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.viewModel.Save();
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public SampleDataItem viewModel { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I would like to find a way (the right way) to go back to main frame (GroupedItemsPage.xaml) at the end of SampleDataSource.SaveFileAsync() method execution and show a MessageDialog of file saved succesfull. Please let me know if I'm not so clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a navigation parameter through **Frame.Navigate** function

```
void Save()
{
    SampleDataSource.UpdateGroup(this);
    SampleDataSource.SaveFileAsync();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "Saved");
}
```

And then, in **GroupedItemsPage** read the parameter sent to the Frame in **LoadState** function and if it is not null show a message dialog with that parameter

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
   if (navigationParameter != null)
   {
        String msg = (String) navigationParameter;
        var popup = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg, "Some title");
        await popup.ShowAsync();
   }
}
```

Comment: Almost there. The private method **Save()** isn't located inside `partial class GroupedItemPage : LayoutAwarePage`, but inside my viewmodel class **SampleDataItem** (I mean that **this.Frame** is not available right now). Should I pass the parent instance of **GroupedItemPage** to my viewmodel constructor (is it a good practice)?

Comment: You can pass the frame or its INavigate interface - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inavigate.aspx

Comment: Doesn't it hurt the principle of MVVM?

Comment: Since the only way to navigate is by calling `Navigate()` on a `Frame` object anyways at some point - you will have to do it. Whether you create some attached property that bound to a view model property will navigate upon a property change event or simply call Navigate() from a view model - it's still going to go that way. Forget about principles of MVVM and think of its benefits and how you want to keep these benefits. MVVM is just a pattern and not a rule. If you want your code testable and it remains so when passing `INavigate` instance - it's fine. Just implement a test `INavigate` class.

Comment: Then you can inject that test implementation to the view model in your test and inject the UI one at runtime. Since `Navigate()` takes a type of a view - you can either break MVVM's View -> View Model graph direction somewhere and allow for this exception or come up with some more complicated contraption like defining a mapping/dictionary between views and view models or raising an event from the view model that requests that the view navigates to the page associated with the new target view model. Maybe create a navigation service outside of your MVVM trio that knows how to navigate where.

Comment: Like @FilipSkakun said MVVM is just a pattern and not a rule. If you "hurt" it using a readable and maintainable way it is fine in my opinion.

Comment: @EduardoSalvador You're welcome and good luck with your project